# Shopping cart framework that supports multiple vendors?

Tags: frameworks, app-store, shopping-cart, webstore

I'm searching for a shopping cart or web store framework that **supports multiple vendors**.

There are [many, many shopping cart frameworks out there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_shopping_cart_software): that page lists couple of hundred.  In spite of the comparisons on that page, supporting multiple vendors isn't a comparison item, probably because it's a rare requirement.  Separate to that page I have evaluated a few of what appear to be the top frameworks, and none that I evaluated supported this feature.  Which carts would you recommend?

- Commercial is okay, although I would prefer open source.
- Platform (Windows, Linux, ASP.Net, PHP, Ruby... Minix, Fortran... :)) doesn't matter.
- A system
  where I manually add vendors who request it (instead of them freely
  being able to sign up) is also okay, if there's a store where that's
  possible but freely joining up isn't built in yet.

---

**Rationale:** I'd like to create an app-store like website.  "App store" is a close analogy: it won't sell apps, but it will sell digital goods and I'd like anyone to be able to sell their item on the store.  It's this second requirement, multiple vendors selling through the store, that I'm finding hard to satisfy.

Comment: Wait a second. Multiple vendor support _is_ on the page you cited. It's the rightmost column of _Other Features_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_shopping_cart_software#Other_Features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used multiple shopping cart frameworks (a lot of them broken), and my favorite (which just so happens to support multiple vendors) is PrestaShop. It's free, open source, and suppports all that you asked for. Is *this* the framework you were looking for?

-JXP

Comment: Thanks... that sounds very good!  I could not see multiple vendors in their full feature matrix PDF, but the bounty expires in a few minutes so I'll award it to you.  Could you go into more detail about why it's your favourite, please?  Is it just reliable / non-broken, or...?

Comment: Well, for one it's open source, non-broken, and supports a lot of different things (multiple vendors, multi store-front, API, etc.) so it's very flexible, even has a way to put add-ons on your prestashop (quite pricey though). Also probably the only SCF that doesn't give me a new error every week :) I'm glad you approve of it!

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page you cited [lists multiple vendor support as a column in *Other Features*](http://Wait%20a%20second.%20Multiple%20vendor%20support%20_is_%20on%20the%20page%20you%20cited.%20It%27s%20stapled%20to%20the%20right%20of%20Other%20Features%3a%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_shopping_cart_software#Other_Features), along with features that are pertinent to your search.

This question otherwise requires domain knowledge and likely requires multiple answers. The best I can do is offer the bounded set of software that competes directly within this space, at least according to Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for the Google link, but... Do you know anything about any of those frameworks?  How many support, say, products simply manufactured by multiple people vs how many are app-store like in that sellers can create their own accounts? Which have good reputations in the community?  Are they all commercial, is there no open-source software that fits that at all? How do any of these match up against the others in other useful ways?  ...I'm hoping for an answer from someone with domain knowledge in the area, not a link to google.

Comment: @DavidM Agreed. I've updated my answer, because I, too, overlooked the column comparing solutions with Multiple Vendor support and ancillary features (like multiple storefronts) pertinent to it. I've also gone through the motions of checking Amazon to see if any product reviews could illuminate this for you and came up empty-handed. So, I concur: the only way to answer this more convincingly will be through the aid of domain experts.

Comment: There is a 'multiple vendor' column on that page....!  *facepalm* Thanks MrGomez.  I'll leave the question up for anyone with experience with different solutions to answer, though.

Comment: @DavidM It's just a thing. Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for achieving your stated goal of allowing multiple people to sell on your site while exercising fine-grained control of who can and cannot do so is perhaps using WPMU's MarketPress in tandem with BuddyPress or WordPress Multisite.  I'm not a die-hard fan of WordPress, per se, but that might be an expedient way for you to get to a minimal viable product and to validate your idea before shelling out the time and/or cash to custom build it from the ground up, and/or labor ad nauseam with tweaking an existing framework.  MarketPress is a good plug-in that'll give you many of the features of a full-fledged e-commerce framework... BuddyPress, of course, will allow you to set up individual vendor's with their own sites under your brand.  The two work together. More on MarketPress at:

```
http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/e-commerce/installation/
```

Another alternative is Jimdo's PagePartners.  I haven't used it, but it looks intriguing.  I like their design sensibilities, and their stated business ethos.  This might be a viable option, too. The caveat being: it's not white label.  More info about Jimdo's PagePartners here:

```
http://www.jimdo.com/pagepartner/faq/
```

Finally, another interesting CMS to explore is SetSeed.  I think it'll allow you to launch multiple sites for each vendor via a central hub you control, and will allow you to maintain your branding within each.  How, the,n any sort of renumeration would flow back to you for setting up an individual vendor's store would be up to you to figure out...  This is a fairly new CMS and it looks like it's evolving smartly and rapidly.  If you require some customization of it, to approach more specifically what you ask for, now might be a good time to reach out to the developer...but you might be able to think of an effective way to adapt it for your use right out of the box.

```
http://setseed.com/multi-site-cms/setseed-hub/
```

Unfortunately, none of the above is open-source--but, again, the ease by which you could get to a functional site approximating your idea may off-set that drawback.  Jimdo is an open-source contributor, however.  So, maybe even an e-mail to them might be a fruitful dialogue to begin.  If anything, check out each of the above, and it may influence how you search for other solutions, and will at least provide some models in your own thinking or with other developers.  The shopping cart is an integrated feature, I believe, in all of the above cases.  With regard to giving your vendors the capacity to deliver digital goods (e-books, mp3s, etc.), check out Fetchapp.com.  Very cool app.  Very easy to set-up...could probably be rolled into one of the above frameworks.  The frameworks would handle the issue of individual vendor profiles and/or sub-domains.